# Quelle est la différence entre « la boucherie » et « la charcuterie » ?

Tags: choix-de-mot, alimentation

Quelle est la différence entre « la boucherie » et « la charcuterie » ?

Je sais que « la charcuterie » signifie autrement « cooked meat » ; est-ce que c'est le magasin pour les charcuteries ? Mais, je l'entendais utilisé en tous les deux, donc quelle est la différence ?

(Parlez plus simplement, s'il vous plaît, parce que j'apprends le français.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

En général, et pour respecter votre demande de rester simple, *la boucherie* vend:

> des viandes **non préparées**

et *la charcuterie* (en effet, c'est un magasin) vend:

> des viandes **préparées**.

En anglais, on pourrait dire que la boucherie c'est comme un "**butcher**" et la charcuterie c'est comme un "**deli**".

Comment: A noter que couramment on utilise aussi boucherie pour une boutique de viande de bœuf ou de mouton, et charcuterie pour la viande de porc et le gibier.

Comment: La charcuterie vend egzlement souvent des plats préparés  (salades, lasagnes, etc.) pas forcément à base de viande.

Answer (score 15):

L'étymologie permet d'éclaircir la différence.

- Une **bouc**herie était l'endroit où l'on vendait de la viande de **bouc** et par extension, toutes les viandes crues (bœuf, mouton, etc.)
- Une charcuterie était l'endroit où l'on vendait des "**chairs cuites**" (*chaircuiterie* en ancien français), préparations directement consommables essentiellement à base de viande de porc (saucisses, saucisson, jambon, paté) mais pas seulement.

Answer (score 3):

> *Charcuterie* :
>
> - Industrie et commerce de la viande de porc et des préparations à base de porc.
> - Spécialité à base de viande de porc
> - Boutique du charcutier.

On différencie les spécialisations : Boucherie-charcuterie, Charcuterie italienne...

Les charcuteries vendent du porc cru et *cuisinent leurs préparations*, *[par extension](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/charcuterie)* elles peuvent vendre aussi d'autres viandes et d'autres produits, on parle alors de charcutier-traiteur.

Une boucherie vend toutes sortes de *viandes crues*, gibier et porc compris.

Un volailler vend toutes sortes de volailles, s'il les fait cuire, il est aussi rôtisseur.

Le tripier, métier en voie de disparition, s'occupe de préparer les *[abats](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/abats)*.

---

- Le charcutier vend à l'origine de la viande de porc crue et ses préparations culinaires, le charcutier-traiteur ajoute tout ce qui peut faire une repas cuisiné.
- Le boucher abattait autrefois les bêtes lui-même, ce travail est maintenant fait et contrôlé par l'abattoir. Il prépare toutes sortes de viandes qu'il vend crues.

Comment: Je ne suis pas tout à fait d'accord avec votre définition de charcuterie. En effet, un charcutier est un commerce vendant de la charcuterie. Or la charcuterie est, de base, de la viande cuisinée et n'est pas obligatoirement du porc : les diverses rillettes de volailles, la viande de grison, les terrines de lapin sont des charcuteries ne contenant pas de porc

Comment: @Garf365 -- Les trois définitions de *Charcuterie* sont celles du petit Robert, de même, il indique que les charcuteries (actuelles) vendent des plats préparés avec d'autres viandes, toutefois, même si l'usage est accepté, beaucoup se disent alors *charcutier-traiteur* pour dire qu'ils sont capables de préparer des repas complets et prestigieux pour des événements importants.

Comment: ma remarque vient d'une lecture de wikipedia, ainsi que différentes autres sources tel que le cnrtl et le larousse, toute disant que la charcuterie est principalement basée sur la viande de porc, mais pas seulement

Answer (score 1):

Pour faire simple, il le semble que le boucher découpe, prépare et vend la viande crue; Le charcutier transforme, cuisine la viande (et de façon traditionnelle s’occupe de la viande de porc).

Comment: C'est vrai mais est-ce que ça donne une nouvelle réponse ?  Voici le [tour] et le [FAQ], et bienvenue sur French SE.